# Multiple IF for 430 argument

Tags: excel

i have a list of 430 rows which set range of phone numbers in

```
**Cabin   From          To** 
Cabin2  22007000    22009999
Cabin3  22010000    22059999
Cabin4  22060000    22075999
Cabin5  22310000    22369999
Cabin6  22370000    22377999
Cabin7  22380000    22399999
```

and i have 1500 phone number need to set which cabin it belong to 
i need a formula that check number in which range and print cabin name 
like this

```
**Phone        Cabin** 
22363998       Cabin5
22365005    
22381790    
22381929    
22478221    
22478222
```

Thanks on advance

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151047/how-to-find-location-based-on-ip-address-in-excel/24151515#24151515

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `INDEX(cabinArray, MATCH(phoneNumber, numberFromArray, 1))`

This will match on the highest value `less than` the `phoneNumber` you lookup.

Set the Cabin column to the Named range `cabinArray` and the `From` column to the `numberFromArray`.

Note that this assumes the ranges cover all possible numbers and you won't be looking up a number outside the range.

**Side note:**

You could use some form of verification by using the more complex:
`if(INDEX(cabinArray, MATCH(phoneNumber, numberFromArray, 1)) = INDEX(cabinArray, MATCH(phoneNumber, numberToArray, -1)), INDEX(cabinArray, MATCH(phoneNumber, numberFromArray, 1)), "Failed to match")`

This checks that the phoneNumber you are looking up is both lower than the `To` and greater than the `From`. It isn't elegant, but it does work `: )`